# How do you switch between built-in audio and headphone audio without unplugging?

Tags: macos, headphones, audio

Once I plug headphones into my iMac I no longer have the option in the sound preferences panel to output audio to the built-in speakers. I have to unplug the headphones to get audio output through the built-in speakers. Since the plug is on the back of the display this is inconvenient. Does anyone know of an audio app that allows me to easily switch between built-in speakers and headphones for audio output?

Comment: If you don't find an app that will over-rule the hardware signal indicating to route the sound to the jack - you can get a [Griffin iMic](http://www.griffintechnology.com/support/imic) or similar product and keep things connected through USB and still retain software control of the sound.

Comment: For some reason I thought [SoundSource](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/freebies/) would do this, but you're right: it's one or the other. To be clear, did this change in Lion?

Comment: No, works the same in Lion

Comment: You should consider adding that as an answer, @bmike.

Comment: I have the same problem here, but I'm sure it can't be only due to hardware.
I recently instaled Bootcamp with Win Vista and I can have sound in both headset and speakers at the same time...

Answer (score 0):

I think the condition has always been there.  I believe plugging into the headphone jack physically disconnects the sound output from the speakers.  I believe you will have to use bmike's suggestion to get the desired outcome.

Comment: If the speakers get physically disconnected when you plug in headphones, how does the startup chime play out of the speakers when headphones are plugged in.

Comment: I believe this is done in software and is not just a physical re-routing of the audio. This is why you get independent volume control on each and when the system is under leavy load it might take a second or more for the audio to switch from one system to the other upon a plug/unplug. So theoretically it should be possible but this might be controlled at a very low driver level.