# Can I make my iMac output audio to the speakers when headphones are plugged in?

Tags: imac, audio, headphones, speakers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you switch between built-in audio and headphone audio without unplugging?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23549/how-do-you-switch-between-built-in-audio-and-headphone-audio-without-unplugging)

When I plug in my headphones the built in speakers are no longer an option for audio output (they literally disappear from the audio output system preferences). This means to switch back and forth I have to walk around my iMac and plug/unplug my headphones. Do I have any alternatives?